# Android How to implement control in notification area

Tags: android, notifications

What is the way to implement control in notification area like music player? API level 9. Image what I need https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG3pQ.png

Answer (score 0):

You can download android support library and use    `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder` class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html

Here's tutorial from Google http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Do you mean use notification's big view for additional controls?

Comment: Unfortunately... 
Not all notification features are available for a particular version, even though the methods to set them are in the support library class NotificationCompat.Builder. For example, action buttons, which depend on expanded notifications, only appear on Android 4.1 and higher, because expanded notifications themselves are only available on Android 4.1 and higher.